# Laravel - Get sum from different table and calculate

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I'm new in laravel and I need help with this. So I have 3 different table as shown below. I have to calculate the quantity of item based on the different value in the two tables. First, I have to get the sum of the value table 1 and table 2 and group it by the item. After that minus the result and display in item table in my blade by the quantity column

Item table

```
|ID | Item    | quantity    |
+---+---------+-------------+
|1  | item1   |             |
|2  | item2   |             |
|3  | item3   |             | 
|4  | item4   |             |
```

Value1 table

```
|ID | Item    | value       |
+---+---------+-------------+
|1  | item1   |   4757.34   |
|2  | item1   |   938.00    |
|3  | item1   |   0.00      | 
|4  | item2   |   6574.3    |
|5  | item2   |   74.40     |
```

Value2 table

```
|ID | Item    | value       |
+---+---------+-------------+
|1  | item1   |   27.64     |
|2  | item1   |   0.00      |
|3  | item1   |   2.00      | 
|4  | item2   |   64.34     |
|5  | item2   |   4.40      |
```

This is what I have done so far

My Eloquent

```
public function getValue1()
{
    $query = Value1::select(DB::raw("SUM(value) as value1"))
                ->groupBy('item')
                ->get(); 
                
    return $query;
}

public function getValue2()
{
    $query = Value2::select(DB::raw("SUM(value) as value2"))
                ->groupBy('item')
                ->get(); 
                
    return $query;
}
```

My Controller

```
$value1 = $myEloquentRepo->getValue1();
$value2 = $myEloquentRepo->getValue2();

$quantity = $value1 - $value2;
```

But it seems like I'm not doing it correctly as I got an error Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not be converted to number. Any guide will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That is much simpler to be done with plain SQL. It will be much faster for the server as there will be 3 times less requests to the database.

```
$query = "INSERT into ItemTable
SELECT t1.item, (t1.qty - t2.qty) as 'quantity'
from (
  select Item, sum(value) 'qty'
  from table1
  group by Item
) t1
join  (
  select Item, sum(value) 'qty'
  from table2
  group by Item
) t2 on t1.Item = t2.Item
";
DB::uprepared($query);
```

*the SELECT query itself will return you the needed result. Then based whether your ItemTable is empty or filled, you insert or update into it.*

Comment: Hi, thank you for this but I only need the quantity to be display in my blade view table not by inserting it into my sql table.